# SQL Server docker container with NFS mount as volume mapping

Tags: sql-server, docker

I am trying to run SQL Server on ubuntu as a docker container using stranded microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest docker image. For the data persistence I am mapping a volume from my host (having ext4 file system) to container using -v option in docker run command like below

```
docker run -it -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=######' -p 1433:1433 
               -v /var/opt/database:/var/opt/mssql/data microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

Container is running just fine and i am able to connect to the database. But I do not want to store data on my host because of the growing size of the database and for swarm reasons. Now I thought to run a NFS server on some other machine and mount the nfs directory onto my docker host and then use that nfs dir on the volume mapping now the volume mapping is

```
-v /var/nfs/database:/var/opt/mssql/data
```

where `/var/nfs/database` is a nfs mount dir on the docker host. Now when I start the container I get the following error

> 2017-08-18 10:15:53.98 spid5s      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 87(The parameter is incorrect.).
>   2017-08-18 10:15:53.98 spid5s      Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
>   2017-08-18 10:15:53.98 spid5s      Unable to open the physical file "/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf". Operating system error 87: "87(The parameter is incorrect.)".
>   2017-08-18 10:15:54.13 spid5s      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2017-08-18 10:15:54.13 spid5s      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf for file number 2.  OS error: 87(The parameter is incorrect.).
>   2017-08-18 10:15:54.13 spid5s      Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
>   2017-08-18 10:15:54.13 spid5s      Unable to open the physical file "/var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf". Operating system error 87: "87(The parameter is incorrect.)".

I have given all the permissions to database files. Below is the nfs mount snippet

> sharedstorageIp:/var/nfs nfs4      443G   47G  375G  11% /var/nfs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes) explain that you can't do this:

> Hosting database files on a NFS server is not supported in this
>   release. This includes using NFS for shared disk failover clustering
>   as well as databases on non-clustered instances. We are working on
>   enabling NFS server support in the upcoming releases.

Hosting database files on a networked path is not trivial, given the demands the database has for reliability. Hosting files on SMB shares wasn't possible until version 2.2 of the protocol.

Comment: Thank you for answering .This makes sense. But i am able to use nfs mount when i am pulling the image using **ctp2-0**  tag. Is is ok to use that image. This again fails when i use **ctp2-1** this concerns me over the stability of the releases. failing with all the releases except ctp2-0.

Comment: @Anand: It's almost certainly not OK to do that, unless you don't really care about reliability. In CTP 2.0 there may have been file system calls that were dummied out just to get things working, that properly report "not implemented" in later releases. Of course, technically, there is no stable release of SQL Server on Linux yet, so if you just want it to experiment, go ahead. It doesn't change the fact that that setup is unsupported and you shouldn't entrust your data to it.